# C++ - Bouncing / Moving open Windows

Tags: c++, windows, move

I saw a Prank Virus - some time ago - which was doing some cool stuff. For example, that all open windows for example the Browser and all other opened Windows moving randomly over the full screen so that the user dont can use them anymore and when the user opens a new window the window starts moving too. How can I do this with C++

Comment: The problem depends on platform OS. In Windows read about WinAPI. In Linux read about XOrg/Wayland. Have a nice lecture

Comment: @LukasDark I'm really not sure whether I should support this, but the following research by google "Windows handle hook" and "get all windows handles of window" provided some promising hits. If "MSDN" appears in the URL, I would prefer these links

Comment: @Scheff I am not going to do "evil" stuff with it when you mean this. I only want troll by friends.